# ggplot2 - Plot coloring does not follow linear scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting an enrichment analysis, with ggplot2 and geom_point(), colouring the points according to pvalue. pvalues are between 4.681209e-05 and 1.724922e-30.

it looks like this:
[image]

everthing seems fine until you look at the colour legend: despite the pvalues going down to e-30 the legend labels are in the range of e-5.
I performed a couple of sanity checks:

1. Since I recolour the plot with the viridis library I removed the
   step and allowed colouring with the default blue hues --> It's not
   viridis.
2. I manually checked the pvalues of the few blue-green-yellow dots: they are indeed in the e-5 range --> the legend label is correct, is the coloring scheme that is distorted. This means that most of the colour space is used up for values between 4e-5 and 1e-5, while all the other values down to e-30 are compressed in colors between dark blue and purple.
3. To check that the whole dynamic range is still in there and not just sliced out, I artificially introduced a 0 in the list of pvalues. As you see now there's an additional label indicating the position of the zero in the dark purple range
   [image]

I would like to have a linear mapping of pvalues to colors across the whole color space, but I can't find any option regarding this setting.
Also, I can't find a reason why such a behavior would't be a default, and what part of my code is messing it up in case it actually is the default.

Thanks!

my code

```
ggplot(top_anatomy, aes(x = sample, y = Anatomy_term, size = n_genes, color = pvalue)) +  
    geom_point() +  
    scale_color_viridis(option="viridis") +  
    ggtitle(paste(top, "most upregulated anatomy terms per sample")) +   
    labs(x = "",  
        y = "Anatomy term",  
        size = "Expressed genes in term",  
        color = "Adjusted p-value") +  
    theme(axis.line = element_line(size=0.5, colour = "darkgray"),  
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),  
        panel.border = element_blank(),  
        panel.background = element_blank(),  
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

and my data

```
# A tibble: 80 x 6  
# Groups:   sample [8]  
sample         Anatomy_term                   pvalue genes     EMAPA n_genes  
<chr>          <fct>                           <dbl> <chr>     <chr>   <int>  
 1 Sample x  mesenchyme                   0.       MGI:1017~ EMAP~     501  
 2 Sample x  paraxial mesenchyme          1.72e-30 MGI:1017~ EMAP~     152  
 3 Sample x  somite                       1.17e-28 MGI:1017~ EMAP~     141  
 4 Sample y  endoderm                     4.50e-28 MGI:1033~ EMAP~     105  
 5 Sample y  trunk mesenchyme             3.93e-26 MGI:1017~ EMAP~     126  
 6 Sample y  embryo mesenchyme            1.74e-25 MGI:1017~ EMAP~     303  
 7 Sample z  alimentary system mesenchyme 1.85e-25 MGI:1017~ EMAP~      84  
 8 Sample z  mesenchyme                   5.00e-25 MGI:1017~ EMAP~     303  
 9 Sample z  embryo mesenchyme            2.33e-24 MGI:1017~ EMAP~     279  
10 Sample j  mesenchyme                   6.21e-24 MGI:1017~ EMAP~     279  
# ... with 70 more rows
```

Comment: You are not going to get linear colour mapping over 25 orders of magnitude. You could try transforming the p-values first, e.g. by taking logs. Also remember that e-30 p-values are not very informative.

Comment: Yes, the log works, I was just hoping to get it without transformation, nevermind. However, could you try to explain why it wouldn't have a linear color mapping over 25 orders of magnitude? If the range is too broad I would understand an error, but not the compression of most of the value to a small part of the color space and the expansion of the rest. In the end it could just set the two extreme colors to the extreme values received and split the colors and values linearly...